# How can i create a custom page for product listing in magento 2

Tags: magento2, module, magento2.2, product-list

i have created a module and i got the respone in phtml but dont know how to design it same as listing help me to create a custom page for product listing in magento 2

Answer (score 1):

make a new theme,
example:
vendor\yourtheme\Magento_Theme\templates\html\custom.phtml

```
<?php if ($welcome_message_content !== "") : ?>
<div id="welcome_message">
    <p> <?= $welcome_message_content ?> </p>
</div>
```

vendor\yourtheme\Magento_Theme\page_layout\custome.xml

```
<update handle="empty"/>
    <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
        <container name="header.container" as="header_container" label="Page Header Container" htmlTag="header" htmlClass="page-header" before="main.content"/>
        <container name="page.top" as="page_center" label="After Page Header" after="header.container"/>
        <container name="top.menu" as="header-wrapper" after="logo"/>
    </referenceContainer>
 <referenceContainer name="columns.top">
        <container name="customhome.view.container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="home-view" after="page.title.wrapper">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="customHomeView" template="Magento_Theme::html/products.phtml" />
        </container>
    </referenceContainer>
```